# Need help in converting the clob to varchar in oracle, I have to use the varchar in case function of oracle

Tags: oracle, pivot

I have a requirement where I have to fetch the data from the `clob` data type , convert to the varchar2, to make a pivot for oracle 10g.

I am using the following

```
select max(case 
             when key='abc' 
             then dbms_lob.substr(value) 
           end) as data_abc 
  from table.
```

if the value is less than 4000 the above query works fine but if it is more than 4000 it shows and error of buffer limit. On reading few blogs I came to know that `dbms_lob.substr()` can handle only 4000 characters in sql but can handle up to 32k in a pl/sql statement.

if I write a procedure and run it, it works fine. but i want to use it in a function. below is my function :

```
create or replace FUNCTION CLOBTOVARCHAR 
RETURN varchar2 is out_attribute_var varchar2(32767) ;
BEGIN
  FOR i IN (select attribute_Value  from car_course_attribute where id=1547156)
  LOOP
    out_attribute_var := dbms_lob.substr(i.attribute_Value, 32000, 1);
  END LOOP;

  RETURN out_attribute_var;

EXCEPTION
  WHEN OTHERS THEN
    raise_application_error(-20001, 'An error was encountered - '||SQLCODE||' -ERROR- '||SQLERRM);
END CLOBTOVARCHAR;
```

If the data is small it works fine but if the data is bigger than 4k, it gives same error back. now I have two questions:
1) Am I doing right by converting the `clob` to varchar2 as I want to get pivot
2) Is my function correct?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unfortunately SQL in Oracle supports varchars up to 4000.
Your function won't work in SQL queries.
You can upgrade to oracle 12c which increases this limit up to 32767 characters.
However there is a simple workaround that works on 11g, here is an example of CLOBs pivot for 3 columns:

```
SELECT (select val from xx
        where rowid = a_rid ) a,
       (select val from xx
        where rowid = b_rid ) b,
       (select val from xx
        where rowid = c_rid ) c
from (
  select max( case key when 'A' then rowid end ) a_rid,
         max( case key when 'B' then rowid end ) b_rid,
         max( case key when 'C' then rowid end ) c_rid
  from xx
);
```

Here is [SQLFiddle demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/ce42f/6) with 3 strings, each of them contains 7996 characters.
A result row in this demo is very wide, it has over 150 "horizontal pages" 
I am surprised that SQLFiddle can display rows 24K characters wide 
A third query in this demo display lengths of pivoted colums, each of them has 7996 characters.

Comment: I tried this on oracle 10g it did not work and gave same error. I will try some workaround and let you know.

Comment: I tried it in 11g, and it worked, after spending 3 hours digging the web for solution. Thank you very much !!

Answer (score 1):

```
dbms_lob.substr( clob_column, for_how_many_bytes, from_which_byte );
```

for example:

```
select dbms_lob.substr( x, 4000, 1 ) from T;
```

will get me the first 4000 bytes of the clob. Note that when using SQL as I did, the max length is 4000. You can get 32k using plsql:

```
declare 
my_var long; 
begin 
for x in ( select X from t ) 
loop 
my_var := dbms_lob.substr( x.X, 32000, 1 );
```

....

This was accurate as of 2016 or so. As of Oracle Database 12c, we now support extended varchars2's - up to a length of now 32k - which may be fewer than 32,000 and change characters if using Multi-Byte character set (2,3,or 4 bytes per character)

Originally answered by Tom [here](https://asktom.oracle.com/pls/apex/asktom.search?tag=converting-clobs-to-varchar)

I have a working scenario for an 8k long string into a varchar2 using just SQL on LiveSQL [here](https://livesql.oracle.com/apex/livesql/file/content_GE3ZQVE6XUEZAPU6XJV22BJWH.html)

The code for a 12c environment with extended varchars enabled.

```
create table long_vars2 (a integer, xyz varchar2(8000), clobs clob);

create or replace procedure p( p_x in int, p_new_text in varchar2 )  
 as  
 begin  
 insert into long_vars2 (a, xyz, clobs) values ( p_x, p_new_text, p_new_text );  
 end;  
/

exec p(1, rpad('*',8000,'*') );

select dbms_lob.substr( clobs, 7000, 1 ) from long_vars2;
```